# Redis Configuration, need to allow remote connections but need security

Tags: security, configuration, redis, iptables

I need my about two EC2 instances which need to connection to an outside redis server. The redis conf is binded to `0.0.0.0` to allow this. Is there some sort of a password/auth system for redis connections? I need to way to allow my servers to connect to remote redis but block everyone else.

I know I can do this with `iptables` by whitelisting only those EC2 ip addresses for port `6379` but I was wondering if there was a proper way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redis sports a very basic form of authentication via password protection. To enable it, you'll need to add/uncomment the `requirepass` directive in your configuration file and have your clients authenticate with the [AUTH](http://redis.io/commands/auth) command.

Another approach would be to use an extra layer of security such as a secure proxy. Here's an howto: http://redislabs.com/blog/using-stunnel-to-secure-redis.

Comment: It's worth spelling out to people here that using auth does not add any encryption to your traffic. Your data you're adding and getting from redis will be plain text and readable by any of the network devices (likely 10s or more) between point A and point B. In short, do NOT set up remote redis unless the data is entirely safe to broadcast or unless you use a secure proxy like stunnel as per Itamar's link.